# A symmetric matrix is indefinite iff it has both positive and negative eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a symmetric matrix $n\times n$ matrix, such that we have the quadratic forms $$Q_1 = x^T A x >0$$ $$Q_2=y^T Ay <0$$

for some $x,y \in \Bbb{R^n}$. Since $A$ is symmetric, it is diagonalizable and $A$ has $n$ distinct eigenvectors - enough to form a basis of $\Bbb{R^n}$.  If we make change of variable such that $x^TAx=y^TDy$. I think that since the values on the diagonal matrix $D$ correspond to the eigenvalues of $A$, that a direct proof could be used for the $\to$ direction here. I'm looking for hints on how to proceed with the proof from here.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the diagonalized matrix $D$ to show the contrapositive of the $\Rightarrow$ direction: if $A$ has only non-negative or non-positive eigenvalues, then it must be semi-definite.